# gitosis and git not pushing/pulling correctly

Tags: git, gitosis, ubuntu-server

Okay, so I've been working at this for quite some time now, and I'm slightly confused as to what's going on.

I've been working on setting up a local git server (running ubuntu 11.04 server and using gitosis) for a class project. However, I can clone the gitosis-admin folder, but any changes I make, and push, don't actually go to the server computer, but I don't yield any errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say they "don't go to the server computer" do you mean they don't show up as refs on the server, or that you have a *working copy*  (checkout) on the server, the files for which aren't updated?

Comment: @Amber, They simply don't show up on the server. I have it sitting next to me, so I'll be watching when I push, and nothing happens in said repo.

Comment: And there aren't any error messages on the push? What is remote origin set to in .git/config?

Answer (score 0):

You might glance at [Git: Cloning gitosis admin repo locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979170/git-cloning-gitosis-admin-repo-locally) - if you happened to install the same version the person who answered that was thinking of, the remedy might be the same:

> How did you install gitosis? I remember there being a common issue where during the install, a required hook in the gitosis-admin repo was not set to be executable. As a result it never updated the config when pushed to.

Comment: Also, As for the permissions errors, I just gave RW perms to everyone using that folder. No permissions errors after that.